# Turkish Char Encoding in R Studio File Path

Tags: path, character-encoding, rstudio

In R studio, where I had no problem before, now when I call the same excel file, the Turkish characters in the file data path cause problems and put a ?? sign. As far as I know this is an encoding problem. Why did the encoding change and how can I solve the problem?

`In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="G:/Drive'ım//MA_2023/MA_2023_ANALİZLER/VERI_APMA_2023_MAB.xlsx": Sistem belirtilen yolu bulamÄ±yor`

System doesn't find the path.

`Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Turkish")`

I tried to run this code, however, it doesn't work for me.